# Infinite while loop in python

Tags: python, while-loop, infinite-loop

No matter what I do, I can't get this while loop to work; unless i hardcode the value in.

```
count = 0
value = raw_input('How many?')
print value
while (count <= value):
        print "a"
        count= count + 1
```

At first I tried using a command line argument, using sys.argv[1] for value but I got the same problem. This seems so simple, yet I cannot for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Try to check - what type is your value? And what type is your count variable?

Comment: After fixing the datatype issues mentioned by others, there's a slightly more concise and pythonic way to write the loop:
for i in xrange(value): print "a".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ensure that value is an integer,

```
while (count <= int(value)):
    count= count + 1
```

By default `raw_input` is a string, and for every integer `n` and every string `s` we have `n<s is True` (!), hence your loop (without the `int`) never breaks.

*Note: In Python 3 comparing string and integers will give a `TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()`, which is probably more "expected" behaviour.*

Comment: Thank you. I didn't even think about that.

Comment: Also note that this now behaves a bit better in Python 3 - '5' < 4 gives an error that tells you exactly what's going on, rather than a meaningless result.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your input to an integer first

```
value = int(raw_input('How many?'))
print value
```

Comment: ... but dont' forget to `try`->`catch` the possible `ValueError`Exception, which can be raised if the input is not a number representation!

Answer (score 1):

By the way, if you really want to get your statement to be `value` times printed change condition from

```
count <= int(value)
```

to

```
count < int(value)
```

or start `count` from 1